# Checar se uma div variante existe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo varias divs com o prefixo de classe "webserver_[..]" e gostaria de checar se alguma div com o prefixo "webserver_[..]" existe, apenas com jQuery, como fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar `^=` que é um [pseudo-seletor que quer dizer que um dado atributo "começa com"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) e assim procurar elementos cuja classe começe com essa string "webserver_".

Exemplo:

```
$('[class^="webserver_"]').length // vai dar o numero de divs existentes
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kbp019v3/